# How to get relative path to an imported file in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following file:

```
import {something} from '../../something';

something.do();
```

And I want to get `something`'s relative path as a string, but dynamically rather than to write it implicitly. Something like this:

```
import {something} from '../../something';

getPath(something); // will return '../../something'

something.do();
```

What are my options? Is it even possible?

Comment: Are you allowed to modify the something file?

Comment: modify how? if it is allowed.. what is the solution?

Comment: well you could export a variable from `something.js` that you would assign a global object: `__filename` to

Comment: so let's not modify the imported file.

Comment: Is something a function? a variable?

Comment: You  want to get the relative path of the "something"?

Comment: it can be anything. i don't really care about the type but just to get the path to it's file.. even if the import statement is: `import {one , two} from '../../onetwo';` i just need `'../../onetwo'`

Comment: You can use path.relative(from, to). From can be given from the current file and to can be given from the file you import from variable import {something, path} from '../../something';

Comment: You could perhaps use `fs.readFile` to try to read the current file and parse it for the list of imports

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara can you implement a short solution so i can better understand please?

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski i look into this option :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a relative path to an imported file as follows

**FIRST APPROACH**: (the imported file is modified):

1. Assume that you have a `test` folder. Inside the `test` folder, you have `test1.js` and `/mod/test2.js` files.

**test/mod/test2.js**

```
// here are some of your codes

export const importedFilePath = import.meta.url;  // export current file absoulte path
```

2. Now inside the `test/test1.js` file:

> path.relative(from, to) method
> returns the relative path from to to based on the current working
> directory. If from and to each resolve to the same path (after calling
> path.resolve() on each), a zero-length string is returned.
>
> If a zero-length string is passed as from or to, the current working
> directory will be used instead of the zero-length strings.
> [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathrelativefrom-to)

```
import path from 'path'
import { importedFilePath } from './mod/test2.js';

const currentFilePath = import.meta.url;

console.log(path.relative(currentFilePath, importedFilePath));
```

Output:

```
..\mod\test2.js
```

Now you have the relative path `from test/test1.js` to `test/mod/test2.js`

*I know this is not a perfect solution but you can achieve the result you want using the above approach.*

**SECOND APPROACH**

**If you would be using the CommonJS module system you can be achieved this result without modifying the imported file.**

Assume you use the CommonJS module. Without any modification to the imported file you can achieve the same result as above as follows:

`test/test1.js` file:

```
const file = require('./mod/test2');
const path = require('path');

const importedFilePath=require.cache[__filename].children[0].id; //this returns imported file path
const currentFilePath = __filename;

console.log(path.relative(currentFilePath, importedFilePath));
```

And output:

```
..\mod\test2.js
```